# Overriding default value for records where outer join fails

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this MySQL query:

```sql
SELECT   event.*, GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', ') as real_name 
FROM     event LEFT JOIN user ON event.organizer = user.id 
WHERE    owner IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY event.id 
ORDER BY startdatetime ASC
```

The output is printed in PHP:

```php
print($zeile['real_name'] == '' ? $zeile['organizer'] : $zeile['real_name']);
```

This works fine, but I asked myself if it's possible to effect the ternary operation in SQL. What I mean:
the `real_name` column of the resultset will take the value of `GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', ')` if the join succeeded, and `event.organizer` if it did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Records for which the join criterion cannot be fulfilled will have `NULL` in every column from the `user` table, including those used in the join criterion itself.  You can use this fact thusly:

```sql
IF(user.id IS NULL, event.organizer, GROUP_CONCAT(forname, ' ', surname SEPARATOR ', '))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IF in your request like that :

For Example :

```
         //  Condition   //Succeded //FAILED                                     
SELECT IF (forname = '', organizer, forname) FROM ......
```